# Edittext change Border Color always onclick

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an edittext and want to change the border color after onclick.
 After I click on it it shows me the red border color.
 But After I try it again nothing happens. It is still red.
first click red -> second click black -> third click red and so on
How can I fix it?

```
...
boolean focus = false

...
    private void setOnFocusChangeListener(final EditText editText) {                           
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                    focus = false;
                } else if (hasFocus) {
                    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                    focus = true;
                } else if ((hasFocus) && focus) {
                    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                    focus = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You want to change the color when clicked on the edittext or a seperate button?

Comment: are you clicking the same `edittext` each time ?

Comment: yes the same and the color of the edittext border

Comment: you should check `StateListDrawable` class

Comment: I only want to change the color after clicked on it.

Comment: How does `focus` variable relates to focused state of an `editText`? I think you should look up changing `editTest` focus property itself...

Comment: just check the built-in states available for `StateListDrawable`

Comment: @pskink this is not the solution. It is on pressed. I want only the action after onlick not on pressed

Answer (score 0):

In your case instead of `onFocusChangeListener()` you can use `onClickListener()` as you want to change on each click, you can do something like this :

```
int res = R.drawable.black; // Your default background

etEmailAdress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (res == R.drawable.black) {
                res = R.drawable.btn_green;
            } else {
                res = R.drawable.black;
            }
            etEmailAdress.setBackgroundResource(res);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need the onfocuschangelistener because to hide the keyboard

Comment: when you want to hide the keyboard ? Any specific condition ?

Comment: the hidekeyboard method is ready. it hides the keyboard if I touch everything except of the edittext

Comment: this is not the solution